# Webpack CSS loader won't parse comments

Tags: reactjs, css-loader, react-starter-kit

I'm using react starter kit and I'm trying to import the SCSS files from bootstrap (installed via NPM) and it's complaining about the comments:

```
    ERROR in ./~/css-loader?sourceMap&modules&localIdentName=[name]_[local]_[hash:base64:3]!./~/postcss-loader!./~/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss
/Users/jamessherry/sites/business_website/node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss:7:1: Unknown word

// Core variables and mixins
^
@import "bootstrap/variables";

ERROR in ./~/css-loader?sourceMap&modules&localIdentName=[name]_[local]_[hash:base64:3]!./~/postcss-loader!./~/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss
Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
    at new Input (/Users/jamessherry/sites/business_website/node_modules/postcss/lib/input.js:31:23)
    at parse (/Users/jamessherry/sites/business_website/node_modules/postcss/lib/parse.js:22:17)
    at new LazyResult (/Users/jamessherry/sites/business_website/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:61:24)
    at Processor.process (/Users/jamessherry/sites/business_website/node_modules/postcss/lib/processor.js:34:16)
    at processCss (/Users/jamessherry/sites/business_website/node_modules/css-loader/lib/processCss.js:188:11)
    at Object.module.exports (/Users/jamessherry/sites/business_website/node_modules/css-loader/lib/loader.js:24:2)
 @ ./~/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss 2:18-178 18:6-24:8 19:25-185
```

Here's the import in app.js

```
import emptyFunction from 'fbjs/lib/emptyFunction';
import './../../../node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss';
import s from './App.scss';
```

Then put it through the webpack loaders:

```
, {
    test: /\.scss$/,
    loaders: [
      'isomorphic-style-loader',
      'css-loader?' + (DEBUG ? 'sourceMap&' : 'minimize&') +
      'modules&localIdentName=[name]_[local]_[hash:base64:3]',
      'postcss-loader',
    ],
  }
```

Does anybody have any ideas why?

Thanks

James

Comment: Are you using this react starter kit. https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit

Comment: @Darshan Yes I am... :)

Comment: So where is your `scss` loader?

Comment: @user1775718 is there any particular reason you are using bootstrap-sass instead of bootstrap

Comment: @zerkms Not sure about your question. The loaders (iso, css-loader & postcss-loader) handles scss processing...

Comment: @Darshan TBH, I only wanted the stylesheets in the beginning. There's nothing to stop me using the Bootstrap module. It was just odd that it faulted on a comment which is legal in SASS...

Comment: @user1775718 "The loaders (iso, css-loader & postcss-loader) handles scss processing" --- no they are not. `css-loader` loads css, and `postcss-loader` by itself does literally nothing and requires additional transformers to be applied. Check this https://github.com/postcss/postcss-scss

Comment: @zerkms If you download the react starter kit (link above)  you can see that all the style files are .scss and those loaders are what handles them (hence the test). That webpack loaders config is written in that kit, not by me. To be fair to you, I struggled to see how those loaders would handle it, but they do... 

I've just downloaded the latest version, so I'm going to test it in that too.

Comment: @user1775718 they have it configured for sure at this line: https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/blob/master/tools/webpack.config.js#L81 + https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/blob/master/package.json#L77 while you don't have anything like that. I'm not sure why you haven't searched for the `scss` string through the config, since it's the easiest way to find it out. "not by me" --- then there should be a good reason on why what you have posted is different from what they have in the repository.

Comment: To anyone else, I'm guessing from what research I've done that the post-css loader loads all the postcss plugins from the node_modules directory. In there is postcss-nested. I think it's interpreted through that (there's certainly no postcss-scss in there...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to load 3rd party `.scss` files with [sass-loader](https://github.com/jtangelder/sass-loader) instead of `postcss`+`precss`+`postcss-scss` parser that comes by default in [RSK](https://www.reactstarterkit.com/).

```
$ npm install sass-loader --save-dev
```

Webpack allows you to configure what [loader](https://webpack.github.io/docs/loaders.html) to use for which file either via `webpack.config.js` (preferred) or explicitly in "import" statements. For example, try adding this line in your CSS:

```
@import '!!sass!../../node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss';
```